# Having trouble running one-way ANOVAs in R on different categories

Tags: r, statistics, lapply, anova

I have a dataset where I want to see if there is a significant difference in growth between  different oyster treatments using an ANOVA test. I apologize if my stats knowledge is rusty and my data is not formatted correctly, but my dataset is in long format and looks something like this:

```
Oyster   Treatment   Length.Difference
1        T1          1.32
2        T3          3.45
3        T4          6.12
4        T4          -0.12
5        T2          3.23
6        T1          5.09
7        T3          -0.92
8        T2          2.32
9        T1          0.09
10       T4          5.11
```

I am trying to see if there is a significant difference between T1 and T2, T1 and T3, T2 and T3, etc. I (unsuccessfully) tried to split the data by class by doing:

```
lapply(split(df1, df1$Treatment), function(i){
  anova(lm(Length.Difference ~ Oyster, data = i))
})
```

If anyone has a solution to my problem, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: If each oyster only appears once in your data frame, then you cannot use the oyster number as a variable in your analysis. If you just want to look at the difference in means between the different T1, T2, T3, T4, then there is no need to split your data. It's just `anova(lm(Length.Difference ~ Treatment, data = df1))`. If each oyster appears more than once and you are looking at repeated measures, then you may need a mixed model approach, but that would be more of a statistical than programming question, best asked over at CrossValidated.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you so much your help!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following approach to compare length difference across the treatment conditions. You can ignore the tibble / tribble parts - I just used them to get your data. To compare each treatment pairwise you will want to use post-hoc testing after the ANOVA model, Tukey's HSD is a popular choice. [This](https://statisticsbyjim.com/anova/post-hoc-tests-anova/) might be a good starting point to learn more about post-hoc testing in the context of ANOVA.

```
# Example data
df <- read.table(text="
Oyster   Treatment   Length.Difference
1        T1          1.32
2        T3          3.45
3        T4          6.12
4        T4          -0.12
5        T2          3.23
6        T1          5.09
7        T3          -0.92
8        T2          2.32
9        T1          0.09
10       T4          5.11
", header=TRUE)

    
# This is the important part
anova_model <- stats::aov(
  data    = df,
  formula = Length.Difference ~ Treatment
)
    
post_hoc_test <- stats::TukeyHSD(anova_model)

print(anova_model)

print(post_hoc_test)
```

Comment: @AkselA , thank you for the smart edits

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RachelDavitt No problem! Make sure to mark this answer as accepted if it works for you so other users know for the future.